# Перенос проекта из gitlab на github

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Можно как-то перенести репозиторий из gitlab на github? Мне дали доступ к частному gitlab репозиторию, я его форкнул к себе на gitlab. Можно теперь его как-то перенести к себе на github с помощью ssh?

Comment: ну можно конечно. Указать гитхаб как удаленные репозиторий и все

Comment: @Эникейщик У меня в конце выскакивает ошибка, если я пытаюсь его импортировать именно на сайте `There was an error pushing commits to GitHub.` Можно как-то это сделать через консоль?

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh Да, я попытался, но при загрузке я получаю ошибку `[remote rejected] ... (pre-receive hook declined)`

Comment: да можно и через консоль конечно. Уверен, что в справке гитхаба это достаточно подробно описано.